# Change "List of Listings" text

Tags: latex, listings, lstlisting

I tried to change the "List of Listings" text with the command

```
\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{List of XYZ}
```

before my `\begin{document}`. What's wrong with this?

By the way

```
\renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{NewListing}
```

worked like a charm.

Edit: No error occurred, just no change in the text. It's still "List of Listings".

By the way this is how I included it:

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

I've seen that on the "List of Listings" page the numbering starts with "1" but it should be a "V". Some hints?

Thank you

Comment: It is always a good idea to tell what happened when you tried it vs. what you expected to happen.

Comment: Maybe some List macro is defined... BTW. welcome:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `\lstlistoflistings`

`\listoflistings` is from the `listing` package. `\lstlistoflistings` is from `listings` package (Notice the plural). You should not use both at the same time.

If you are using the `listing` package, use

```
\renewcommand*{\listlistingname}{List of XYZ}
```

to change the heading.

EDIT: From the fact that `\lstlistingname` works I conclude that you use the `listings` package. I suggest to remove the line `\usepackage{listing}` from your tex file. If you use both packages: Just use the right commands. Listings from both package appear in both put the entries into the same `lol` file.

Comment: If I add \renewcommand*{\lstlistoflistings}{New Section Title} to either the preable or document, the section title of the list of listings changes (from "Listings"), but the entries disappear (i.e. I get an empty page with a section header only).  What am I missing?

Comment: Using that command your replaced the `listings`'s definition of a Table of Listings by the text "New Section Title". Change \listlisting**name** to change only the heading.

Answer (score 20):

Just tried to change it myself. There is a separate command that provides the name. E.g.:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{My listungs}
```

so both `\lstlistingname` and `\lstlistlistingname` need to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

For answering your page numbering question:

Insert a `\cleardoublepage` just before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. That should fix the roman numbering on your List of listings.

Answer (score 1):

Non of above answers worked for me. The commands that solved my issue were:

```
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Code}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{List of source code examples}
```

Note: the commands above are for the Listing package, not for the Listing**s** package!